# Pycharm does not display database tables

Tags: python, django, sqlite, pycharm

After updating PyCharm (version 2017.1), PyCharm does not display `sqlite3` database tables anymore.

I've tested the connection and it's working.

In `sqlite3` client I can list all tables and make queries.

Someone else has get this problem? And in this case could solve anyway?

Comment: [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/working-with-the-database-tool-window.html#open_db_tool_window) may or may not help

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, Pycharm seems stupid on that, I've stubled upon the solution with a bunch of luck:

1. Make sure you have all schemas shown: [db->Schemas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzY6B.png)
2. Still, the tables do **not** show..until you select the db and hit Reload: [Cmd+R or Context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAODT.png)

Comment: In my installation (2023.1) the key to Refresh is CTRL+F5.

Answer (score 2):

I am using PyCharm Professional v2017.3.

In Database pane, click the plus button and add `Data Source -> Sqlite (Xerial)`. `Data Sources and Drivers` settings will open up where you will see `Driver: Sqlite (Xerial)`. This **does not mean** drivers are fully installed. Look at the bottom-left of the pain for a message. If it has a warning sign about missing files, install missing files. Otherwise it will say `no objects`.[image]

Answer (score 1):

After clicking on the `View => Tools => Window => Database` click on the green plus icon and then on `Data Source => Sqlite (Xerial)`. Then, on the window that opens install the driver (it's underneath the `Test Connection` button) that is proposing (`Sqlite (Xerial)`).

That should do it both for `db.sqlite3` and `identifier.sqlite`. I have never any problem with Sqlite database, showing on PyCharm IDE.

Comment: @Caco. If you press the `Test Connection` button and you get a success, what does the `Details` *link* (next to it) shows?

Comment: Details of `Test Connection`: `Database: SQLite (ver. 3.16.1) Identifier case sensitivity: mixed (plain), mixed (delimited) Driver (JDBC2.1): SQLiteJDBC (ver. native)`

Comment: I suppose that you hit synchronise, don't you?

Comment: Yes, when I make any changes in the database I hit synchronize to update Pycharm database representation.

Answer (score 0):

It might be stupid thing but consider that you have to connect actual DB and not only indentifier.

The fastest way is to double tap on the DB file in the file explorer and Pycharm will automatically suggests everything.

[Pycharm screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhjeI.png)

Comment: @NameVergessen Can you tell me what exactly doesn't work? If you want to see the DB sqlite tables just double tap on the db.sqlite3 file and it suggests to create a connection. Btw it's not a fix it's a suggestion ;)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I am using Pycharm 2022.3.2 Version. I was trying the hit and try method for hours now and it seemed to work for me.

1. `View-> Tool Windows-> Databases`[image]
2. Once Databases Open on the left side pane.
   Click on the `+` button and choose `Data source from Path[image]
3. Then choose the path of your `db.sqlite3` file and click `open`[image]
4. After that Choose the drive from the drop down and choose `sqlite` and click `OK`
   [image]
5. The db should work fine now and tables should be populated as per the data. Atleast mine did. Try this and let me know if that works!!!
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm 2023.3.2 (Professional Edition) on the Database toolbar, there is a "+" for adding a source. In the dropdown menu from the "+", the first choice is to specify a data source by database. Don't choose that.

Skip down to "Data Source by Path". That works!